# Key-Based Caching in Play Framework with Scalaz Involved

Tags: scala, playframework, scalaz

I am attempting to do some key-based caching for my Play Framework application. Here is the code for the handler at my endpoint:

```
optionT(findById(id)).map { thing =>
      val cacheKey = thingCacheKey(thing)
      cached(cacheKey) {
        Action.async { implicit request =>
          val result = //Produce a result—probably Ok(“content”)
          } yield result    
        }
      }
}.run.map {
  case Some(actionF) => actionF
  case None => Action.async(Future.successful(NotFound()))
}
```

As you can see, I am using Scalaz's `optionT` monad transformer.

Not terribly surprisingly, I get this error:

*Cannot use a method returning scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.EssentialAction] as a Handler for requests*

Can you show me how to return a `Result` rather than `EssentialAction` with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play cache api has not any monadic composers nor has it `Action` so really need to run actions up to `Iteratee` which has [`flatten`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$@flatten[E,A](i:scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[E,A]]):play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[E,A]) method that could unwrap this `Future`. This is example of successfully compiled approach

```
Action.async { implicit request => Iteratee.flatten {
  optionT(findById(id)).map { thing =>
    val cacheKey = thingCacheKey(thing)
    val action = cached(cacheKey) {
      Action.async{
        Future(Ok)   // replace with your processing of "request"
      }
    }

    action.apply(request)
  }.getOrElse(Iteratee.ignore[Array[Byte]].map(_ => NotFound))
}.run
}
```

Here we unwrapping `OptionT` transformer via `getOrElse`, not via `run.map{ }`, and then running `Iteratee` to `Future[Result]`

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. But you need to return an `EssentialAction` out of the `cached` block, and you didn't account for the `run.map` stuff you need to do with `optionT`. Those are the things that are giving me trouble.

Comment: @Vidya `.getOrElse` of `OptionT[F, X]` is returning `F[Option[X]]` so you dont need additional `run` here http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.OptionT

Comment: @Vidya Why do you need to cache `Action`s which are essentially request handlers? Is not it sufficient to cache `Result`s?

Comment: @Vidya sorry, I meant `.getOrElse` is returning `F[X]` which is `Future[Result]` in this case, so result type of .getOrElse is perfect for `Action.async`

Comment: It isn't that I am looking to cache an `Action`. It is just that the the `Cached` class [demands](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.cache.Cached) it. The [documentation example](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaCache) shows the same.

Comment: @Vidya Updated the answer. Using of *Play cache API* worth noting in the question text

Comment: Clever approach (and upvoted accordingly), but now I have an issue where the value is never being cached. So I am finding cache misses every time.

Comment: @Vidya. Yes, seems like `Cached` like any other `ActionBuilder` operates in pure-functional way. Second Inaccuracy is  despite text in answer [there is way to compose Actions asynchronously](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaActionsComposition) . I think in general there is a way to make it via [`ActionTransformer`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.ActionTransformer) I will elaborate on answer enhancing little bit later.